# Отправка формы в новое окно

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго дня.

Я столкнулся с проблемой, суть которой в следующем. Имеются фрейм и две формы:

**Код HTML**

```
<iframe id='iframe_1' style='display:none'></iframe>

<form action='my.php' method='POST' target='iframe_1' id='form_1'>
<input type='text' name='text_1' value='Hello Wolrd!' />
<input type='submit' value='Отправить' />
</form>

<form action='http://other_site.ru/other.php' method='POST' target='new_window' id='form_2'>
<input type='text' name='text_2' value='ASDF' />
</form>
```

**Код JavaScript**

```
function new_window() {
    var new_wind = open("", "new_window");
    document.getElementById('form_2').submit();
}
```

Порядок действий таков:

1. Пользователь нажимает кнопку Отправить в форме номер 1.
2. После проверки данных на сервере, скрипт **my.php** вызывает из ифрейма **iframe_1** функцию **new_window()** для создания нового окна.
3. Функция **new_window()** создаёт новое окно и пытается отправить в него форму номер 2.

Проблема в том, что браузеры блокируют создание нового окна. Причина блокировки мне понятна. Соображения безопасности и всё такое. Но как можно обойти эту бяку? Есть ли какие-нибудь кроссбраузерные решения? Я пробовал воспользоваться dispatchEvent() и fireEvent(), чтобы сымитировать Клик и вызвать функцию **new_window()**, но браузер всё равно блокирует создание нового окна. Я в недоумении.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Всплывающие окна блокируются, если пользователь не указал в настройках иного. И это не обходится, также, как нельзя залогиниться без пароля и т.д.

Решение: не используйте всплывающие окна. К примеру, можно создать скрытый див с `position: fixed` и показывать его над другими элементами когда нужно. Соответственно, оформить его как окно, добавить кнопку закрытия и т. д.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807271/how-to-launch-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load